# C# KeyCode for { and }

Tags: c#, keycode

What is the C# key code for '{' and '}', so I can use it in a `KeyDown` event

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.CurlyBracket1)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Sorry it's a bit vague but I don't know what else to put

Comment: Press the key, then set a breakpoint in the debugger and look at the `KeyCode`.

Comment: Check out [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2814617-cd58-41d0-94b9-e6064249b93f/what-event-to-use-to-trap-composite-keystroke?forum=vblanguage) for a lot of info on capturing composite keystrokes.

Comment: Which of the several hundred keyboard layouts in common use did you have in mind?  Wrong event, use KeyPress instead.

Comment: if (e.KeyChar == 123)
    {
      // User pressed '{'
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == 125)
    {
      // User pressed '}'
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Standard U.S. keyboard layout, the keys for `{` and `}` are `OemOpenBrackets` (or `Oem4`) and `OemCloseBrackets` (or `Oem6`), respectively.  However, since these glyphs share a key with the square brackets (`[`, `]`), you would need to test for the presence of one of the shift modifiers.

I would not assume this would work on all non-"Standard U.S." keyboard configurations; it would be better to handle the `KeyPress` event and check the `KeyChar` property.

Comment: This will only work if the keyboard's language has a key especially for { and }.

Comment: Again your revised answer assumes that Shift + [ = { which may not be the case for all languages.

Comment: Indeed.  Addendum added.  Was trying to locate the alternate API--it's been a while since I've touched WinForms :).

Answer (score 2):

Curley braces are not a Key on all keyboards, for example they require you to hold shift on a UK Qwerty keyboard therefore KeyDown will not work. You need to use the KeyPress event instead.

Answer (score -3):

Check if it is useful: http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

Best regards

Comment: @alacerda - Thanks: It worked - I used in my `KeyPress` [not `KeyDown`] Event `if (e.KeyChar == 123)` for `{` and `if(e.KeyChar == 125)` for `}`

Comment: Nice non-answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this! I really needed it for the longest time.. :)