# What is the keycode of these characters? - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, enumeration

I'm working ona code editor based on Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF). I wanna automatically add close bracket when the user add an open brakcet. But in `System.Windows.Input.Key`, I can't find a keycode for brackets. I also need a few more character codes mentioned below in the code section.

```
//  Brackets, square brackets and curly brackets "("  ")" "[" "]" "{" "}" 
//  Lower/Greater: "<" ">"
//  Equal, quote and single quote " ' =

private void htmlcode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Key = /* the keycode that I need */)
   {
      htmlcode.Text = htmlcode.Text + "<close variant of key>";
   } 
}
```

I need the names of these characters in `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum.

Comment: I'd say you haven't tried to search for this in Google... I have just search for these {} and got the solution from SO. Please before posting a question try to find if it's already answered

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez But you won't bother telling OP what you found? I'd also be curious to see the single keycode of e.g. `{`. On my keyboard, it's three consecutive key codes...

Comment: I will try to google.

Comment: @Clemens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937122/c-sharp-keycode-for-and here he asks for {} . There people suggests to have keypress event instead of keydow, take a look

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez There's no KeyPress event in WPF, and no KeyCode property in KeyEventArgs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# KeyCode for { and }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937122/c-sharp-keycode-for-and)

Comment: @BurakYeniçeri There are no Key enum values in WPF for these characters. Better handle a TextChanged or similar event.

Comment: @Clemens I know there is no `KeyPress` on WPF. I answered you for the "three consecutive key codes". Here, I think he should use TextInput event.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez You commented on the question with "... and got the solution from SO". So which solution that works in WPF? Provide a link to what you found that works with WPF, otherwise your comment is pointless.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez can you give more help about that? Because still I don't know the value of them in enumeration.

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez This is literally the first result on google for what I searched so telling him he didn't google hard enough is very ironic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.Windows.Input.Key` enum has no values for these characters.

You may however handle the `PreviewTextInput` event instead of `KeyDown`:

```
private void htmlcode_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Text)
    {
        case "{":
            // add "}"
            break;
        // etc
    }
}
```

Comment: `PreviewTextInput` should be triggered when text inserted via Ctrl+V. so `e.Text` can be a long string which may or may not contain brackets

Comment: @ASh True, but in that situation OP probably doesn't want to auto-add closing brackets.

Comment: idk. `"{{"` invites 2 closing }. `"{ "` can be closed too.

Comment: @ASh Sure, that leaves some programming work for OP.